# Stiefel Whitney class of a representation $\rho\colon D_{2n} \to O(2)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory, characteristic-classes

As the title suggests, I'm trying to figure out what is the Stiefel Whitney class of the following representation of $D_4=\langle a,b \mid a^2=b^2=1, bab=a^{-1}\rangle=\Bbb Z_2\langle a\rangle \oplus \Bbb Z_2\langle b \rangle$, the usual Klein group.
$$ \rho \colon D_4 \to O(2)$$ $$ a \mapsto \begin{matrix}
 -1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 \\
\end{matrix}$$ $$ b \mapsto \begin{matrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 \\
\end{matrix}$$

this representation induces a map $B\rho \colon BD_{2n} \to BO(2)$, and therefore it represents a well-defined 2-vector bundle. So it makes sense to compute the S-W classes of it. There is a way to prove that the first S-W class is $b \in H^1(D_{2n};\Bbb Z_2)=\hom(D_{2n};\Bbb Z_2)$, but I'm not aware of methods for computing the second S-W class.

I'm not very expert in representation theory (not at all honestly), I'm a topologist (well, I'm studying topology) that's why the question.

Comment: Can you give me any reference about this kind of things?

Comment: What do you mean reference? How I encountered this problem?

Comment: About stiefel whitney classes on this context..

Comment: Well, $B\rho$ is a map into $BO(2)$ so it is a bundle, so we can speak about S-W classes. Anyway, there is a paper here http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869389903098

Comment: Thank you a lot! Let me know if you find something useful!

Comment: You're welcome. Sure =)